# Count regression for a response that have a strict upper bound

Tags: generalized-linear-model, count-data, poisson-regression, ordered-logit

I wonder what is the optimal way to conduct count regression when the response variable has a strict upper bound.

For example, I would like to relate some predictors to how many lung lobes are affected by a disease and there are 5 lobes in total.

Or is such a situation better represented using an ordered logit regression?

Or maybe I should rephrase the problem and instead of modelling the number of lung lobes I should model the rate of lobes infected, that is the number of lobes infected over 5?

Comment: Is that not perhaps rather a binomial outcome - perhaps with some way to reflect that there is a respondent effect (leading e.g. to beta-binomial regression or a generalized linear mixed effects model with a random respondent effect)?

Comment: Maybe I gave a wrong example. I edited the question, so I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Are the binary events per lobe independent within patient? This would e.g. be violated if the disease spreads from one lobe to the next.

Comment: Or if there is a patient specific risk. I'd think a model with e.g. a random patient effect (of course you could go even fancier like taking proximity of lobes into account) would be one logical option.

Comment: Independence of lobe events is a good question that I think would need more of the field-specific knowledge to answer. Moreover the data I have specifies only an ordinal variable that goes from '1 lobe infected' to '5 lobes infected'. That's why I thought that using rates or ordered-logit may be a good solution. Rates are good because they have well-defined upper bound that is explicitly addressed in the model and ordered-logit could be good since, well, it is ordered.